# VBA passing userform controls as parameters

Tags: vba, ms-word, external, userform, caption

I want to have the `.Caption` of a userform label modified by a Sub which is located in another module.

```
  Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim Vs_Label as string
    Label_S.Caption = "something"

    Call ChangeLabel(Vs_Label)
    Label_S.Caption = Vs_Label

    Call ChangeLabel(Label_S.Caption)
  end

  Sub ChangeLabel(Vs_Label)
    Vs_Label = "something else"
  end
```

The 1st time the procedure is called, it returns `Vs_Label` = "something else".
The 2nd time the procedure is called it returns `Label_S.Capiton`= "something".

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: @Warcupine the `Vs_Label` argument is (implicitly) passed `ByRef`, so the caller *does* see the new value.

Comment: The claim makes no sense, there's no way the 2nd call to `ChangeLabel` can ever result in the caption being anything other than "something else". OP must have left an important piece out of the picture here.

Comment: The second call does not pass a variable to the function but a property. Might be the reason. The property return a temporary variant/string witch is then passed to the sub, so only the temp variable is modified, not the property value.

Comment: @VincentG that is correct. The `ByRef` pointer is effectively lost, and the 2nd call has no side-effect whatsoever.

Comment: Side note, a procedure whose job is to get the caption for a label on some form, should probably be in that form's code-behind. Keep UI concerns in UI code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Sub ChangeLabel(Vs_Label)
> ```

First, let's make things clearer by making all the modifiers and types explicit.

```
Public Sub ChangeLabel(ByRef Vs_Label As Variant)
```

We're given a local variable named `Vs_Label`, whose initial value is `vbNullString`.

> ```
> Dim Vs_Label as String
> Label_S.Caption = "something"
> ```

At this point `Vs_Label` is still `vbNullString`, and `Label_S.Caption` is "something".

> ```
> Call ChangeLabel(Vs_Label)
> ```

Now we're passing the `Vs_Label` variable pointer to the procedure, which assigns it to "something else". Note that this would be equivalent, and arguably cleaner code:

```
ChangeLabel Vs_Label
```

After this statement returns, `Vs_Label` is "somethign else", and `Label_S.Caption` is still "something".

> ```
> Label_S.Caption = Vs_Label
> ```

Now both `Vs_Label` and `Label_S.Caption` contain "something else".

> ```
> Call ChangeLabel(Label_S.Caption)
> ```

This call is different now: we're not passing in a variable reference, but a member expression.

So the member expression gets evaluated ("something else"), and a reference to *that value* (which the caller isn't holding on to) is passed to the procedure, which assigns it to "something else" (no change), ...and then the reference is discarded: the 2nd call has no effect whatsoever.

So at the end of the procedure both `Vs_Label` and `Label_S.Caption` are both "something else".

In order for the `Caption` of the label to be "something", at the end of that code, you'd need to have different code.

Place a breakpoint near the top of the procedure (F9), run the code, and use F8 to step through and inspect your labels and variables as you go: you'll find that this code has nothing to do with why the label says "something".

Verify what instance of the form you're working with, in the two places you're looking - and make sure both places are working with the same object instance. The `Activate` handler will run *every time the form is activated* - if the form isn't being shown as a modal dialog, then this could be multiple times per instance.

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu. Am I right in understanding, that there is no way of directly changing the values of UserForm controlls with an outside procedure, by passing them on as parameters?

Comment: When you pass `foo.Bar` as an argument to a procedure that receives a `ByRef` parameter, the `ByRef` assignment cannot be made, because you're passing **the value** of `foo.Bar`, not a pointer to the `Bar` property of the `foo` object.

Comment: That said, UI concerns should be handled in UI code - a standard module has no business doing anything with some form's labels, or any other control for that matter.